# Asterisk chan_mobile concurrent calls

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

New to Asterisk here.

I've setup my phone as a gsm gateway using bluetooth adapter. I then direct calls from the mobile device to a queue that has one member. The member is a soft phone.

`extensions.conf` looks like:

```
[incoming-mobile]
exten => s,1,Answer()
same => n,Queue(support)
same => n,Hangup()
```

This works pretty well. I get the call to the sip soft phone. However, while the call is active, if I receive antother call to my phone device, that call deosn't even reach asterisk. I see the multiple call notification on my phone but it does not go through to asterisk. So my questions:

1. Is it even possible to queue concurrent calls via `chan_mobile` or does that kind of thing require more advanced hardware (e.g. gateways with multiple channels)
2. Even if I had some gsm gateway with 30 sim cards, what happens to the 31st call. How do people handle queuing the calls, once all channels are taken? Seems like it's certainly possible

Any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Some facts

1) chan_mobile not support any gsm gateway, it is clearly stated in project docs.

2) there are no gsm gates or channel drivers supporting second call on same gsm sim card.

3) There are no even PHONES which support that. On all phones you have pause/hold first caller to get second call.

Nobody need this feature, so no expect it will be developed in near future.

Comment: #1 Not true. I've done it and it works pretty well. #3 Yes but what I want to know is if phone can forward both incoming calls to some other agent e.g. Asterisk

Comment: That just mean your gsm gate is usual phone. Anyway, i not know any device or even phone with public-availible CLI which support forwarding of call.